# Determining the population mean

Tags: statistics, means

So I asked 10 random people in the gym some questions and this is how it went:

1. Do you know how to swim?
   If the person responded no then I was not allowed to ask them any more questions. However, if the person responded yes then I had to ask them their age. In addition, I took note of their gender.

Basically, I have a table that looks something like this:

[image]

Now, my professor wants us to do this question:
Estimate the average age of males and females who can swim in San Francisco.

So what I did was took the sum (which was $150$) of the age and divided by $10$ and got the average age to be $15$.

Now this is where I am confused:
My professor asked "Include your best guess as to what the population mean will be" but how would I be able to get the population mean from this data if this is a sample?

Also, the professor gave a part for correlation and said "Describe direction, form, and strength of the relationship." However, don't you need two different variables to create a relationship? In this case, the only variable is age.

Comment: The sentence "Describe direction, form, and strength of the relationship." doesn't use the word "correlation".  Does that word appear?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I thought correlation relates with strength of the relationship?

Comment: It seems that you didn't capture all of the problem statement. There could be additional parameters such as the probability that a person can swim or the average age per gender.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am beginning to see that there are probably additional parameters. I shall look more into it. thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Include your best guess as to what the population mean will be"

It turns out that the sample average $\bar X$ is an unbiased estimator of the population average $\mu$:
$$E[\bar X] = \mu.$$
Thus, the sample average is your best guess.

> However, don't you need two different variables to create a relationship?

Yes, you do. You're being asked to make some inference regarding age and gender. In which case, you have all the information needed: age and gender.

Comment: There certainly are two variables here: age and sex.

Comment: so in order to guess, I would have to be confident to claim that my sample average is the population average. In this case, my total is 10, wouldn't that be too small?

Comment: There is no need for confidence. The mathematical fact is that your best guess is your sample average. Since it is your best guess, my answer is no, it is not too small.

Comment: Alright, great thanks guys!

Comment: @mika : You can also base a confidence interval for the population average on your sample average.  You'd get a rather long confidence interval if your sample is small.

Comment: Actually, you calculated wrong, your average age is 15, not 10.

Comment: @MichaelHardy one of the questions for this assignment is to create a confidence interval for the population average. So i shall take what you said into account

Comment: @probablyme i got 15. I just divided by 10

Comment: @probablyme oh i see what you are thinking. I meant to say that isnt my sample size too small?

Comment: Oh god, sorry I'm really tired. I reread your question, and yes, it is particularly small. With a small sample size of 10, your confidence intervals are going to be affected. The larger your sample size, the better your estimate will be. That's how it tends.

Answer (score 1):

You have two variables: age and sex.  For sex you can use an indicator: $0$ for male and $1$ for female or vice-versa.

You cannot **know** the population mean, but you were asked to **estimate** it based on the sample.

Whether your sample is representative of those who were at the gym might bear examination.